# In next-auth how to avoid the extra step "Sign In With Cognito" and directly go to the sign-in form?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cognito, next-auth

In my Next.js project, when I use Cognito for sign-in (using the next-auth library), I get a first step of clicking a button that says "Sign in with Cognito". When that button is clicked, the sign-in form appears. How can I make cognito not show that first step of "Sign in with Cognito"? I need it to go straight to the Sign In.
The step I want to skip:
[image]
The step I want to go straight to:
[image]

Haven't found anything helpful in the Hosted UI page in Cognito (in the AWS console).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your components where you call signIn() function to trigger authentication, use signIn('cognito') instead.

Comment: Thank you! This was it. I wonder what the logic is behind this. Cognito is the only provider I have in my project so I wonder what passing that parameter actually changed

Comment: So the "Sign In With Cognito" button is actually coming from next-auth and not from Cognito itself? And by specifying Cognito as a provider I get to skip that step since the user doesn't have to manually choose the provider anymore?
Btw, just accepted your answer as the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: So basically when you call signIn(), next-auth doesn't know which provider you are trying to use (because it supports multiple providers). So it provides you with the second step to confirm. By passing 'cognito' as an argument you are informing next-auth about the provider, therefore, avoiding the second step.